# What does it actually mean by max or min of a random variable?

Tags: probability

I've been looking trough Google for getting the answer, yet still I haven't found the exact meaning of it.

What does it exactly mean that one wants to evaluate $max$ or $min$ of a random variable?
I know for instance $max\{1,2,3,4\} = 4$. In the same way for min, it equals 1.

But let say we have idependent random variables $X_1,X_2...\in N(0,1)$ and we define $N=min\{k\mid X_k\geq 0\}$. What does this exactly mean? Is $N$ a order statistic? If i don't know the size, how can I find the maxima or minima?

Confused...

Comment: $N$ is the smallest index $k$ such that $X_k \geq 0$, and so $$P\{N = k\} = P\{X_1 < 0, X_2 < 0, \ldots, X_{k-1} < 0, X_k \geq 0\} = 2^{-k}, ~ k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$$ that is, $N$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: how did you find out that N is geometric such that P(N=k)=2^-k?

Comment: Independence of the $X_i$ gives that $$P\{X_1 < 0, X_2 < 0, \ldots, X_{k-1} < 0, X_k \geq 0\} = P\{X_1 < 0\}P\{X_2 < 0\}\cdots P\{X_{k-1}<0\}P\{X_k \geq 0\} = 2^{-k}$$ since each of the $P\{X_i < 0\}$ as well as the $P\{X_k \geq 0\}$ equals $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, $N$ has the _same_ probability mass function as a geometric random varoable with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, one considers for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$ the set $A(\omega)=\{k\in\mathbb N\mid X_k(\omega)\geqslant0\}$ and, if $A(\omega)\ne\varnothing$, the integer $N(\omega)=\min A(\omega)$. (Recall that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb N$ has a minimum. To be complete, we also mention that if $A(\omega)=\varnothing$, then $N(\omega)=+\infty$.)

Thus $N(\omega)=n$ if and only if $n\in A(\omega)$ and, for every $k\leqslant n-1$, $k\notin A(\omega)$. It happens that $N$ is a random variable because what we just said shows that, for every $n$,
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega\mid N(\omega)=n\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_n(\omega)\geqslant0\}\cap\bigcap_{k\leqslant n-1}\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_k(\omega)\lt0\},
$$
hence the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid N(\omega)=n\}$ is measurable, that is, $N$ is a random variable, as soon as every $X_k$ is a random variable.